# How to create a masonry layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have recently started learning android and now I am trying to create a notes taking app like google keep but I wanted to know that how can I create the masonry layout like that of the google keep.

***Thanks in advance***

Comment: Can you add a screenshot for reference?

Comment: `The screenshots are available on the download page of the play store` this doesn't help, because the app can be changed at any given time and expecting people to download an app just to help you is asking for too much, so you should include enough detail in your post for people to understand what you're trying to do, for people in future as well

Comment: The first one? If yes, then that's possible with recyclerview.

Comment: @GahanVig whenever you ask question you should provide more details also checkout the guidelines on how to properly format the questions

Comment: i did not downvote your answer, i'm sure others would have good reason to do so

Comment: No I upvoted the answer, not downvoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create view using the `RecyclerView` and use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` to create masonry layout Effect.

For further details on how to implement this you can check [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-in-android-with-example/) example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer The link was helpful

Comment: If it works for you kindly accept the answer too :)